# Does the Play framework come with an included email templating library or tool?

Tags: java, email, scala, playframework

I'm looking to create templates for standard emails - such as signup confirmations, status change notifications and other kinds of emails that are usually expected from a web app.

The particular web app I'm working on is using the Play framework. I'm wondering - is there a standard library or tool, included with the Play framework (or usually used by those relying on the framework), for writing and templating these kinds of emails?

[Currently on Play 2.1 RC 1]

Comment: Write at least which version you are using, we're not wizards to guess that

Answer (score 1):

Werner Vesterås wrote that, but deleted :)

For Play 2.x check Play Authenticate by Joscha Feth - it uses multilingual email templates with reflections, however if you don't need to use many languages you can also just use simplified view rendering, which is similar to common Result building, but you need just use `toString()` method with the `render()` to pass it to the mailer as a content.